# Drupal 7 multilingual site: each node URL is duplicated in all languages

Tags: drupal-7, multilingual

I have a Drupal 7 multilingula site with 3 languages: english, arabic, and chinese.

It all work well, but I've just noticed that pages that are not translated have a duplicated URL for each language.

For example say I have www.example.com/node/12 (default language = English). This node doe snot have any translations.

However www.example.com/ar/node/12 and www.example.com/zh/node/12 both exist and point to the English page. They are even being index in Google.

How can I make these URL show a "Page not found" (which should be the expected behavior)?

Comment: Curious, what module are you using for the multilingual feature?

Comment: I use i18n (I think it's listed as "Multilingual content" in the list of modules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end I solved it with some custom code in hook_init:

```
$lang_name = $language->language ;
if ($lang_name == "ar" || $lang_name == "zh-hans") {
    $has_translation = false;
    if ($is_node) {
      $translation_array = translation_node_get_translations($node->tnid);
      $has_translation = isset($translation_array[$lang_name]);
    }
    if (!$has_translation) {
      $path = drupal_get_path_alias(current_path());
      $installed_languages = language_list();
      $en = $installed_languages["en"];
      drupal_goto($path, array('language' => $en), 301);
    }
  }
```

So, basically, on each page I check if we're on a language other than English (which means we're in a path starting with /ar or /zh). If that's the case and if we're on a node I check if there's an existing translation for that node and that language. If so we do nothing, but if not we redirect to the default path (without the language prefix).

Answer (score 1):

There is an other way to translate your content, you can use the [Entity Translation module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation). With this module, you can say that your content is not fully translatable, but just some fields on it (or all if all are translatable). With this system, you have just one node for each language, and this is a better things, if you navigate to your "ar/node/12" the node will be in arabic, if you navigate to the "zh/node/12", the node will be in chinese.
And generally this is better because there is some fields that doesn't need to be translated because it's the same in each language, like an entity reference, an address, etc.

Don't hesitate if you have other question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Isn't that a similar set up to "internationalization", though (except that it's by field)? I am also currently getting one node for each language. The problem is that I'm also getting these extra URLs.

Comment: Yes it's similar to internationalization, the difference is in the content type edit, you can choose between entire node translation or field translation. And if you choose field, you don't duplicate node, just field that are translatable.